# how do i convert a string into a variable name?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, variables

i have a program making the string "aX". i'm then putting it into an equation where i need to call the variable that i named aX.

```
letters = "abcdefgh"
for i in letters:
   posX = i + "X"
   posX = int(posX)
   posY = i + "Y"
   posY = int(posY)
```

can someone help my figure out how to call aX and aY instead of a string?

i tried converting posX and posY into integers , but i cant because it is trying to convert the string "aX" into an integer.

Comment: Rather than do it like this, it's *much* better to keep your variables in a dictionary.  Then you can just index into it, and you won't be polluting your namespace.

Comment: Dictionary keys can have any string name you want. Why do you want to make custom variable names dynamically?